# How to create Select with the given Minimum and Maximum Quantity

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist

I got `product.minimum_quantity__c = 1` and `product.maximum_quantity__c = 10`..

How can i display it in visualforce? is there any for loop like method?..
I think `<apex:repeat>` will not work on this..

```
<select class="select">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: if you have a custom controller or extension, you can do it in the apex and bind the filtered dataset to your VF page element. if you are using standard controller, you can try using Javascript to build the dataset collection you need using min & max value and then use apex repeat binding to that collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vamsi mentioned you can use a variable in your controller (a list of integers) which you can use with `apex:repeat` or alternatively you can stick some javascript:

```
<select class="select" id="mySelect"></select>

<script>
    var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");

    for (var i = {!product.minimum_quantity__c}; i <= {!product.maximum_quantity}; i++)
    {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = i;
        option.value = i;
        mySelect.add(option);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hello sir.. this working for single ticket with minimum and maximum numbers.. the problem is that i have multiple tickets with different minimum and maximum quantity.. i hope you get me..

Comment: Use the above example and extend it for multiple. It's basics... :)

Comment: <td><select class="select" id="{!product.Id}"></select></td>

Comment: i change to that and use var mySelect = document.getElementById("{!product.Id}");... its working now.. thanks a lot!!! :)